# UIView border has different widths. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, border

Here is the picture : [image]

I tried first with buttons, and then with UILabels on top of UIViews but the problem remained the same. Here's my code:

```
    interView = UIView()
    interView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    interView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
    interView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4).CGColor
    interView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 70)
    interView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(interView)
```

So, I would like my UIView to have the same widths on every side of its border. Why is this happening?

Comment: Comment out the shadow. Does the border look better?

Comment: Your border width needs to be a multiple of `1 / screen scale`, you can't color only part of a pixel

Comment: rmaddy No. I actually added it thinking it might be a default shadow that was causing this. @dan You Seem to be right. I searched about it and it makes sense. I set up the borderWidth = 1.0/UIScreen.MainScreen().scale but the problem continues. If I set borderWidth to 1, the width is just too gross, and I want something delicate. Funny thing is: In simulator the borderWidth is perfect (all sides have equal width) and I read something about retina, so in this case, I believe it is my device (iPhone 6s Plus) that is causing this. Anyway, is there any solution for my case?

Comment: @rgoncalv Are you using Display Zoom on device by any chance? That's bound to throw off pixel accuracy. At any rate, I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: Another problem could be running in the simulator as a scale less than 100%.

Comment: Also worth noting that the way iPhone 6(s) Plus renders content *could* be impacting your results. This is because its logical coordinate system's scale doesn't match the physical display's scale, therefore [pixel bleeding can occur](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/11/iphone-6-plus-screen/). Although I doubt this is the root cause of your problem, as your results look far worse than I'd expect from a slight downsampling.